# :before border in datapicker

Tags: html, css

I have datapicker like this http://pokit.org/get/?fec9e8af4aa6af07f290705fff6a5769.jpg

This is my code

```
#ui-datepicker-div:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block; 
    left: 15px;
    top:-9px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    border-right: 9px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01) !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Border is white and not visible on white background if I put `border-bottom: 9px solid #ddd`. Background of caret has color `#ddd`.

I need only border like on datapicker in image.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve... do you want a white border or `#ddd` border?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking and offtopic by why this code isn't working without a working example and explanation of desired result

Comment: I want border on before #ddd and background #fff, like on datapicker, so that it fits with datapicker

Comment: On image is :before caret, has white color and isnt visible